# How to specify a dependency graph when generating files with CMake?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, protocol-buffers, build-system

I'm integrating [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) files compilation in my project's [CMake](https://cmake.org/)-based build process. Currently I'm using the following CMake script:

```
set (TARGET_NAME ProtobufMessages)

file (GLOB_RECURSE PROTOBUF_FILES "protobuf/*.proto")

set (HEADER_FILES "")
set (SOURCE_FILES "")

foreach (FILE ${PROTOBUF_FILES})
  string (REPLACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} FILE ${FILE})
  string (REPLACE ".proto" ".pb.h"  HEADER_FILE ${FILE})
  string (REPLACE ".proto" ".pb.cc" SOURCE_FILE ${FILE})
  list (APPEND HEADER_FILES ${HEADER_FILE})
  list (APPEND SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILE})
endforeach ()

add_library(${TARGET_NAME} STATIC
  ${HEADER_FILES}
  ${SOURCE_FILES}
  ${PROTOBUF_FILES}
  )

set_target_properties (${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES
  FOLDER ${COMMON_PROJECTS_FOLDER_NAME})

set (PROTOBUF_COMPILE_COMMAND
  ${CONAN_BIN_DIRS_PROTOBUF_RELEASE}/protoc
  --cpp_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf
  -I${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuf
  ${PROTOBUF_FILES}
  )

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf
  COMMAND ${PROTOBUF_COMPILE_COMMAND}
  DEPENDS ${PROTOBUF_FILES}
  COMMENT "Compiling protocol buffer files ..."
  )

source_group (TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES
  ${PROTOBUF_FILES}
  )

set_target_properties (${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES
  FOLDER ${COMMON_PROJECTS_FOLDER_NAME}
  )

target_link_libraries (${TARGET_NAME}
  CONAN_PKG::protobuf
  )
```

It works fine, but the problem with this approach is that when a single `proto` file is changed all the files are regenerated.

A simple modification of this approach with calling `add_custom_command` in a loop partially solves the problem:

```
set (PROTOBUF_COMPILE_COMMAND
  ${CONAN_BIN_DIRS_PROTOBUF_RELEASE}/protoc
  --cpp_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf
  -I${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuf
  )

foreach (PROTOBUF_FILE ${PROTOBUF_FILES})
  string (REPLACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} TEMP_FILE ${PROTOBUF_FILE})
  string (REPLACE ".proto" ".pb.h"  HEADER_FILE ${TEMP_FILE})
  string (REPLACE ".proto" ".pb.cc" SOURCE_FILE ${TEMP_FILE})

  add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${HEADER_FILE} ${SOURCE_FILE}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf
    COMMAND ${PROTOBUF_COMPILE_COMMAND} ${PROTOBUF_FILE}
    DEPENDS ${PROTOBUF_FILE}
    COMMENT "Compiling ${PROTOBUF_FILE} ..."
    )
endforeach ()
```

But there is still a problem, because `protobuf` supports including one `protobuf` file into another:

```
import "myproject/base.proto";
```

In this case when `base.proto` is changed the files including it also must be recompiled. Actually the dependencies can form an arbitrary [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). Although the current problem is arising specifically with `protobuf` files compilation this is relevant to all code generation steps when some of the input files can depend on some of the other ones.

Is it possible to solve this problem with CMake?

Comment: If a source file changes that other files depend on, those files need to be recompiled. No way around that.

Comment: @Jasper Juhl I'm not asking for way around that, but how to integrate dependency graph into CMake build process.